# Markov Chain: transitioning to multiple states at the same time

Tags: markov-process

I'm trying to calculate Customer Lifetime Value using Markov Chains. I'm following the paper by [Pfeirer and Carraway](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=B60592C9D2F168D364102B02BFE00858?doi=10.1.1.318.2302&rep=rep1&type=pdf).
The paper evaluates CLV over a finite time horizon `T = 1` period. My scenario is slightly different.
Looking at row = 1:
A customer at a bank begins their journey by acquiring a product (p1,p2,p3) at `T = 0`.
After 1 year a customer has a 10% probability of acquiring p1 again, 15% p2, 30% p3 or 40% will buy no other product. These proportions sum up to 105% because a customer could acquire multiple products during the year.

```
      p1   p2   p3   none
p1    .1   .15  .3    .5
p2    .5   .3   .2    .3
p3    .2   .12  .25   .1 
none   0    0    0    1
```

My question is whether there is another way I could write up the transaction matrix so that the row is equal to 100%?

Comment: "50% of those customers will purchase p1 again, 50% will purchase p2 and 10% will not purchase anything." -- How do you get 110% of customers?

Comment: @BruceET I actually think that you have answered my question. I just need some time to understand it better. My main issue was that the row did not equal to 1 because the customer can purchase product 1 and 2 during the period. But it looks like the solution to this is to have another state p1&p2.

Comment: @Glen_b - Currently each period is defined as 1 year. So during the year a customer (customer A) that started off with p1 will buy p1 again, that same customer will also buy p2 during the same period. So customer A will buy both p1 and p2 at the during the same period. That's how I get the sum of row to be more than 100%. I think that maybe BruceET has helped me understand that I need additional states where a customer has p1&p2.

Comment: @jmich738. Thanks for letting me know that the idea of adding an extra state 'both' helped you to understand this as a Markov Chain. (I'm 'undeleting' the answer.) // While you may eventually be interested in using `eigen` in R to find steady state distributions, you may just want to note the answer at this stage.

Comment: @jmich Ah. yeah, sorry I forgot what you were asking halfway along. For a Markov Chain you need to set it up to have mutually exclusive states.

Answer (score 1):

**Four-state, discrete time Markov chain.** Consider a 4-state chain with (disjoint) states: 'only p1', 'only p2', 'both', and 'neither',
denoted `1`,`2`,`b`, and `n`.  Here is a transition matrix I made up (not assuming product purchases at any one step to be independent).

```
P = matrix(c(.3,.3,.2,.2,  
             .4,.4,.1,.1,
             .2,.2,.5,.2,
             .2,.2,.2,.4), byrow=T, nrow=4)
```

Then the transition matrix $P$ has rows that sum to $1.$

```
P
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.3  0.3  0.2  0.2
[2,]  0.4  0.4  0.1  0.1
[3,]  0.2  0.2  0.4  0.2
[4,]  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.4
rowSums(P)
[1] 1 1 1 1
```

This is clearly an ergodic chain because all elements of $P$ are positive.
Its steady state vector $\sigma,$ such that $\sigma P = \sigma,$ is also
its limiting distribution.

**Solving for the steady-state distribution.** The steady-state distribution vector $\sigma$ can be found in R using the `eigen`
procedure. We use the transpose of $P$ `t(P)` because R finds right eigenvectors
and we need a left eigenvector.

In the output, the eigenvector of smallest modulus, listed first, is the one we want. For an ergodic chain it will be real, with values *proportional* to $\sigma.$ So we use bracket notation `[]` to isolate that eigenvector.

In general, some of the other eigenvectors may not be real, so we use
`as.numeric` to strip any unnecessary complex-number notation from the
eigenvector we want.

```
g = eigen(t(P))$vec[,1]
sg = as.numeric(g/sum(g))
sg; sum(sg)
[1] 0.2857143 0.2857143 0.2142857 0.2142857
[1] 1     # check that elements sum to 1
sg %*% P  # `%*%` signifies matrix multiplication in R
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.2857143 0.2857143 0.2142857 0.2142857
```

So $\sigma = (0.2857143, 0.2857143, 0.2142857, 0.2142857).$
Over the long run, almost 80% buy *something* each year.

Comment: The relevance of this example to the problem is obscure.  The special features of the problem are (1) it is a Markov chain in *continuous time* and (2) the OP has not tracked sufficient information to estimate its parameters.  Note that there cannot be any probability of transitioning from a state in which a product is purchased into a state in which no products are purchased!

Comment: @whuber, my thoughts: I took it (original version) to be discretized to one-year steps. If continuous time, I would have expected a $Q$-matrix of transition intensities (negative for leaving a state), not a $P$-matrix, with what I took to be a complaint that rows did not sum to 1. In the discrete context, my suggestion is to start with proper states to make an ergodic $P$-matrix. // Will delete my Answer if you think it is a distraction.

Comment: @whuber - I actually thought that the error was the probability of going from no purchased product to purchased product? In my scenario I'm only looking at customer who have made a purchase in period 1. But it is possible for them to no buy anything in period 2. For example, there is a 10% prop of someone who has bought p1 in the current period to buy nothing in the next period. What do you mean that I did not track sufficient information to estimate parameters?

Comment: This 4-state discrete time chain with one 'step' each year seems to work OK if the 'product' is renewable roughly on an annual basis (magazine subscription, season tickets for local football team, etc.) Then as long as you have a subscription in effect for magazine 1 you stay in state `1` (or maybe `b`), but transition to another state if you don't renew.